# Using asyncio ioloop with pyzmq

Tags: python-3.5, python-asyncio, event-loop, pyzmq

I want to create a tcp server with zmq sockets. The following code creates the tcp server with use of zmq sockets using python's asyncio's ioloop.

In the following code, I am creating the zmq socket to listen to the incoming connections. The coroutine  `recv_and_process` creates a socket to listen the connection and have a while loop to respond the incoming connection.

My question is how to eliminate the `while` loop and instead use the exsiting `asyncio event loop` ?

```
import asyncio
import zmq
import zmq.asyncio

zmq.asyncio.install()
ctx = zmq.asyncio.Context()

@asyncio.coroutine
def recv_and_process():
    sock = ctx.socket(zmq.PULL)
    sock.bind('tcp://127.0.0.1:8888')
    while True:
        msg = yield from sock.recv_multipart() # waits for msg to be ready
        print(msg)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(recv_and_process())
```

Comment: Placing an infinite while loop is a common pattern in a coroutine to do something repeatedly. As I know there is no option for event loop to delegate the work on its own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understood what you want, but here some thoughts: when we say "asyncio event loop" we mean some global object that executes coroutines in your script. You're already using this event loop by running it until coroutine `recv_and_process` done with line `loop.run_until_complete(recv_and_process())`.

Running asyncio event loop to execute coroutines doesn't mean that your program shouldn't have plain `while` loop statements. While loops can be used for same purpose as always - to do something repeatedly, for example, including awaiting of some coroutine as is in your case.